# Maven Apache on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven

I'm trying to run a Maven Apache project on java and i'm using the Eclipse IDE.

right now i'm stuck with this error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigValue` which I can't find anything to overcome it.

The problem is caught by this line of code

`SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myApp").setMaster("local").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);`

The problem is on the second line of code. More specifically: `JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);`

I'm using Eclipse Luna 4.4.2, Java version: 1.8.0_65, Apache Maven 3.3.9.

Comment: You should post the relevant maven pom configuration, especially the dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include [**this**](http://java2s.com/Code/Jar/t/Downloadtypesafeconfig2101jar.htm) jar to your project and you are all set!